# Mp3 file to Base64 encode string conversion in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, filereader

I have a function to encode an mp3 file to base64 string.But when the file get executed some errors are generating.My function is follows :

function recordAudioToBase64() {

```
console.log('encodeing fun reached');
var file = 'jivebirdrecord.mp3';
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFile, fail);
```

}

function gotFile(fileSystem) {

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("jivebirdrecord.mp3", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {

```
fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
```

}

function gotFile(file) {

```
readDataUrl(file);
```

}

function readDataUrl(file) {

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    base = evt.target.result;
  };
  reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

}

function fail() {

```
 console.log('failed......');
```

}

And i have the following error :

**processMessage failed: Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

processMessage failed: Stack: TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

```
at FileReader.readAsDataURL (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/FileReader.js:201:33)

at readDataUrl (file:///android_asset/www/js/script.js:293:14)

at gotFile (file:///android_asset/www/js/script.js:283:4)

at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/requestFileSystem.js:52:25
at success (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/fileSystems-roots.js:40:13)

at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:292:54)

at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1039:21)

at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1076:13)

at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:944:17)

at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:939:5)

processMessage failed: Message: S01 File810616738 

 [{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"temporary","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/data\/com.phonegap.helloworld\/cache\/","filesystem":0,"isFile":false,"name":""},
```

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"persistent","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///storage/emulated/0/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"content","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"cdvfile://localhost/content/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"files","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///data/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/files/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"files-external","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/files/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"documents","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///data/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/files/Documents/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"sdcard","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///storage/emulated/0/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"cache","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///data/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/cache/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"cache-external","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.phonegap.helloworld/cache/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},

{"fullPath":"/","filesystemName":"root","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:///","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}]**

Please help me to find a solution for converting an mp3 file to base64 string using phonegap and jquery mobile.
Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

It's bit late but for others this might help.

```
directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
                                for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                                    var reader = new FileReader();

                                    var entry = entries[i]; 
                                    entry.file(function(file){
                                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                            reader.onload = doOnload(entry.name);

                                    });

                                }
                            });
```